# How to reuse slices in redux-toolkit and handle multiple states

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

My app is a diary with several pages. Each page has certain areas, each area contains some content within itself. Typically, this is either a kind of a single list, or several such lists.
More specifically:
The first page contains 2 areas:

1. Important things. The area itself contains a todolist.
2. Important events. The area contains a eventlist.

The page for the month contains a few more areas. One of the areas consists of several todolists.
The problem is that multiple areas of the page(s) can use lists there. To reuse the code, I used the createSlice function.

```
interface IList<T> {
  id: number;
    items: T[];
}

interface IListState<TList extends IList<TItem>, TItem> {
    list?: TList;
}

export interface ITodo {
id: number;
subject: string;
done: boolean;
}

export interface ITodoList extends IList<ITodo> {
}

interface ITodoListState extends IListState<ITodoList, ITodo> {
    readonlyHeader: boolean;
}

export const todoListInitialState: ITodoListState = {
    list: null,
    readonlyHeader: true
};


export const createTodoSlice = (listName: string) =>
createSlice({
    name: listName,
    initialState: todoListInitialState,
    reducers: {
        setTodoList(state, action: PayloadAction<ITodoList>) {
            state.list = action.payload;
        },
        updateList(state, action: PayloadAction<ITodoList>) {
            state.list = action.payload;
        },
        addTodo(state, action: PayloadAction<ITodo>) {
            state.list.items.push(action.payload);
        },
        updateTodo(state, action: PayloadAction<ITodo>) {
            state.list.items = state.list.items.map((item) =>
                item.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : item
            );
        },
        deleteTodo(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
            state.list.items = state.list.items.filter(
                (todo) => todo.id !== action.payload
            );
        },           
    },
});

export type TodoSlice = ReturnType<typeof createTodoSlice>;

export const createTodoThunks = (slice: TodoSlice) => {
    const actions = slice.actions;
    const listService = todoService.list;
    const listItemService = todoService.items;

    const setList = (list: ITodoList): AppThunk => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(actions.setTodoList(list));
    };

    const updateList = (list: ITodoList): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
        await listService.update(list);
        dispatch(actions.updateList(list));
    };

    const addOrUpdateListItem = (listItem: ITodo): AppThunk => async (
        dispatch
    ) => {
        if (!listItem) return;

        if (listItem.id === 0) {
            await listItemService
                .create(listItem)
                .then((listItemId) =>
                    dispatch(actions.addTodo({ ...listItem, id: listItemId }))
                );
        } else {
            await listItemService
                .update(listItem)
                .then((_) => dispatch(actions.updateTodo(listItem)));
        }
    };

    const deleteListItem = (listItemId: number): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
        if (listItemId === 0) return;
        await listItemService.delete(listItemId);
        dispatch(actions.deleteTodo(listItemId));
    };

    return {
        setList,
        updateList,
        addOrUpdateListItem,
        deleteListItem,
    };
};

reducerA = createTodoSlice('A').reducer;
reducerB = createTodoSlice('B').reducer;
```

Reducer for page

```
export const mainPageReducer = combineReducers({
    somePageAreaA: reducerA,
    somePageAreaB: reducerB,
});
```

Ok, this works. But now in another area I need to store the state of several lists there.
And here I am a little confused. I will have a separate state for this and can use createEntityAdapter, but how can I centrally dispatch actions for each state?
How do I, for example, correctly add an item to one of the lists?

```
const adapter = createEntityAdapter<ITodoListState>({
    selectId: (listState) => listState.list.id,
});

const slice = createSlice({
    name: "multipleTodoLists",
    initialState: adapter.getInitialState(),
    reducers: {
        itemAddedOrUpdated(state, action) {
        //how can I avoid duplicating addOrUpdateListItem logic from todoSlice?
        adapter.updateOne(??)
        }
    }
});
```

About reducers, I could create something like a cache of reducers, so that when `setLists` are called and lists are passed there, slices would be generated for each of them and reducers would be taken. And in the `itemAddedOrUpdated` code, I would find this reducer in the cache and run a single list through it and then update the general state through `updateOne`.
But I don’t know at all how to deal with thunks. I tried to add a code that seems to work, but I don't like it at all.

```
export const addItem =
    (listId: number, newItem: IListItem): AppThunk =>
    async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const slice = createTodoSlice("todoList_" + listId);
        const listState = getState().multipleTodoLists.entities[listId];

        const createdItemId = await listItemService.create(newItem);

        const newListState = slice.reducer(
            listState,
            slice.actions.addItem({ ...newItem, id: createdItemId })
        );

        dispatch(multipleTodoListsSlice.itemAddedOrUpdated(newListState));
    };
```

Tell me the direction in which I need to move. Or maybe redux-tookit won't help me here at all and I need to change the structure as a whole?